# Linear Regression and Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, statistics, linear-regression, logistic-regression, linear-models

I'm a beginner, and I'm wondering whether a logistic regression in a nut-shell is just normalizing a linear regression? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I came to this conclusion because the predicted value of logistic regression is simply just the linear regression's prediction put into a sigmoid to get 0 and 1. So, logistic regression = normalized linear regression?

Comment: Hi, do you mean normalized like in transformed? (I mean, normalization returns values in the whole real number spectrum)

Comment: i meant normalization where u scale the numbers to between 0 and 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Both are unified under the term [Generalized Linear Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model).